# What is the role of UINavigationTransitionView, UILayoutContainerView and UIViewControllerWrapperView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

What is the role of `UINavigationTransitionView`, `UILayoutContainerView` and `UIViewControllerWrapperView`? What is their lifecycle?

Comment: It's private API; nobody who doesn't work for apple will be able to give you a definitive answer. I believe they are all used to facilitate transitions and presentations of various other UIKit components.

Comment: Even the ones who do work for Apple would not be able to give me answer, since it's under NDA. I'm interested in how they implemented it and what would be the best practices if I wanted to build an open source clone from scratch.

Comment: I wondered this myself. I've made a from scratch version of a navigation controller using a single view (constrained to the size between the navigation bar and bottom of the screen) to which I add child view controllers. This seems to work fine, so I can't see why Apple uses such a complex hierarchy.

Answer (score 6):

Apple probably uses such a complex view hierarchy to support a clean separation of concerns. The transition view is probably concerned *only* with transitioning the child view controllers while the layout view is concerned *only* with laying them out in different interface orientations. This could let them re-use the logic for layouts in the tab controller (where the transition logic is not needed).

As others have pointed out, all this is conjecture, so no one can give you a definite answer. Good luck implementing your controller!